# Pushing DIV's after slideToggle is executed

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I am currently working on a portfolio piece project and the problem I am running into is as following : I have three products on each line, there are six total projects. What I want to happen is that for when a top box is clicked, the bottom content will slide down with it, but it only does that for the last product on the top line.

Here is link to what it is: http://cheyneosy.com/SS1/outerwear.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your floats. Add a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to your `.product-container`.

```
.product-container:before,
.product-container:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table;
}

.product-container:after {
    clear: both;
}
```